# Pandas parser error when empty CSV column starts showing values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a long CSV file (150Mb+) which I am attempting to import, and when `read_csv` is used, pandas reports this error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 26 fields in line 6100, saw 27

So I checked line 6100, and on the right you can see that one of the columns - which was completely empty up to this point - starts showing values,

[image]

My CSV file has 26 columns in the header, with the rightmost column corresponding to one of them, and I have tried different combinations of options, all the way up to

`df = pd.read_csv(file_location, header=0, index_col=0, na_values = ["", 0]).fillna(value = 0)`,

to no avail.

Shouldn't Pandas treat empty cells as `N/A`'s? Why would this cause such a problem?

Comment: nothing concrete but when your first value is `nan` python does some autotyping which leads to error like this one, so maybe that's happening here

Comment: Just add one column name in your header

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the values in column 7 don't contain the delimiter you're splitting on?